# In ARKit, Can I select any real world object to bind virtual objects with it, using depth map or other techniques?

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, shapes, feature-detection

I am wondering how to implement this in ARKit: I have a bottle on the table and I want to add a "small hat" on it, by circling the aimed object like I did with red pen in the pic.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJ8QX.jpg)

Also, if the bottle is partly hidded, it can also be selected. Can I implement this bound between any real object and virtual objects in ARKit? Maybe using depth map or sth.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shsZV.jpg)

Thanks a lot!